# Exporting document content from SP2013 to external webapp

Tags: document, export, rest, json

How should I do to make a document viewable on a webpage, that is exported from SP2013 document library. 
A user should be able to,  through a webpage send a request to view the content of a specific document. .DOC .PDF for example.

My searches so far has pointed me towards REST and JSON.

Would really appreciate someone pointing me at the right direction.

Comment: Maybe I should convert the file to binary, send it GET it to the Webapp with REST and compile it to a file there. Presenting it in a view with javascript.
Thoughts?